# How do I setup a git driver to ignore a folder on merge?

Tags: git, git-merge

I have the master branch, where all the main code resides, and the design branch, where the layout of the rails application is built by the design team. They have added a folder called "photoshop" to the public folder to keep their sources for the images also under version control. But I don't want this folder to be copied on merge to the master branch because, well, it is not needed.

Apparently, the way to do this is through a merge driver. So, I've created the "ignore" driver:

```
[merge "ignore"]
name = always ignore during merge
driver = ignore.sh %0 %A %B
```

And created the ignore.sh file on my $PATH:

```
exit 0
```

I've created the .gitattributes file inside public/, because the photoshop folder should be ignored in whole and it is going to appear under public/:

```
photoshop  merge=ignore
photoshop/ merge=ignore
photoshop/* merge=ignore
photoshop/**/* merge=ignore
```

As you can see, I've tried several different patterns to ignoring the whole folder, but it does not work. I believe this is because there is no folder on the master branch, so there's no conflict and so git doesn't use the ignore driver. Is there a way to achieve this without having to create a public/photoshop folder on master?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I tell git to always select my local version for conflicted merges on a specific file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928646/how-do-i-tell-git-to-always-select-my-local-version-for-conflicted-merges-on-a-s)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As suggested by my other answer, here goes the extended, generalized, industrial-strength version of the solution.

*(yes, I was bored at home and had nothing else better to do :P)*

This script will add a new, *detached* commit based on your *local* design branch, so it won't affect neither the design repository or your design branch. The commit will have all desired files removed. Then it performs the merge.

For those too lazy to read the full code, the "core" of these steps can be simplified as:

```bash
original=$(gitbranch HEAD)    # current branch name, or sha1 if not in a branch
branchsha=$(gitsha "$branch") # sha1 of a ref, to force detached commit

git checkout "$branchsha"   &&
git rm -rf "${files[@]}"    &&
git commit -m "$msgcommit"  &&
newsha=$(gitsha HEAD)       &&
git checkout "$original"    &&
git merge -m "$msgmerge" "${mergeopts[@]}" "$newsha"
```

And here is the full script:

[git-strip-merge](https://github.com/MestreLion/git-tools/blob/master/git-strip-merge)

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#
# git-strip-merge - a git-merge that delete files on branch before merging
#
#    Copyright (C) 2012 Rodrigo Silva (MestreLion) <linux@rodrigosilva.com>
#
#    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
#    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
#    (at your option) any later version.
#
#    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#    GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#    along with this program. If not see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
#
# Answer for "How to setup a git driver to ignore a folder on merge?"
# See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111515

#Defaults:
msgcommit="remove files from '<branch>' before merge"
msgmerge="Merge stripped branch '<branch>'"
verbose=0
quiet=(--quiet)

usage() {
    cat <<- USAGE
    Usage: $myname [git-merge options] [-M <commitmsg>] <branch> FILE...
    USAGE
    if [[ "$1" ]] ; then
        cat >&2 <<- USAGE
        Try '$myname --help' for more information.
        USAGE
        exit 1
    fi
    cat <<-USAGE

    "git-merge that delete files on "foreign" <branch> before merging

    Useful for ignoring a folder in <branch> before merging it with
    current branch. Works by deleting FILE(S) in a detached commit based
    on <branch>, and then performing the merge of this new commit in the
    current branch. Note that <branch> is not changed by this procedure.
    Also note that <branch> may actually be any reference, like a tag,
    or a remote branch, or even a commit SHA.

    For more information, see <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111515>

    Options:
      -h, --help
         show this page.

      -v, --verbose
         do not use -q to supress normal output of internal steps from git
         checkout, rm, commit. By default, only git merge output is shown.
         Errors, however, are never supressed

      -M <message>, --msgcommit=<message>
         message for the removal commit in <branch>. Not to be confused
         with the message of the merge commit, which is set by -m. Default
         message is: "$msgcommit"

      -m <message>, --message=<message>
         message for the merge commit. Since we are not merging <branch>
         directly, but rather a detached commit based on it, we forge a
         message similar to git's default for a branch merge. Otherwise
         git would use in message the full and ugly SHA1 of our commit.
         Default message is: "$msgmerge"

      For both commit messages, the token "<branch>" is replaced for the
      actual <branch> name.

    Additional options are passed unchecked to git merge.

    All options must precede <branch> and FILE(s), except -h and --help
    that may appear anywhere on the command line.

    Example:
      $myname design "photoshop/*"

    Copyright (C) 2012 Rodrigo Silva (MestreLion) <linux@rodrigosilva.com>
    License: GPLv3 or later. See <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>"
    USAGE
    exit 0
}

# Helper functions
myname="${0##*/}"
argerr()  { printf "%s: %s\n" "${0##*/}" "${1:-error}" >&2 ; usage 1 ; }
invalid() { argerr "invalid option: $1" ; }
missing() { argerr "missing ${2:+$2 }operand${1:+ from $1}." ; }

# Option handling
files=()
mergeopts=()
for arg in "$@"; do case "$arg" in -h|--help) usage ;; esac; done
while (( $# )); do
    case "$1" in
    -v|--verbose  ) verbose=1            ;;
    -M            ) shift ; msgcommit=$1 ;;
    -m            ) shift ; msgmerge=$1  ;;
    --msgcommit=* ) msgcommit=${1#*=}    ;;
    --message=*   ) msgmerge=${1#*=}     ;;
    -*            ) mergeopts+=( "$1" )  ;;
    *             ) branch="$1"
                    shift ; break        ;;
    esac
    shift
done
files+=( "$@" )

# Argument handling

msgcommit=${msgcommit//<branch>/$branch}
msgmerge=${msgmerge//<branch>/$branch}

[[ "$msgcommit" ]]  || missing "msgcommit" "MSG"
[[ "$branch"   ]]   || missing ""          "<branch>"
(( ${#files[@]} ))  || missing ""          "FILE"

((verbose)) && quiet=()

# Here the fun begins...
gitsha()    { git rev-parse "$1" ; }
gitbranch() {
    git symbolic-ref "$1" 2> /dev/null | sed 's/refs\/heads\///' ||
    gitsha "$1"
}

original=$(gitbranch HEAD)
branchsha=$(gitsha "$branch")

trap 'git checkout --quiet "$original"' EXIT

git checkout "$branchsha"  "${quiet[@]}" &&
git rm -rf "${files[@]}"   "${quiet[@]}" &&
git commit -m "$msgcommit" "${quiet[@]}" &&
newsha=$(gitsha HEAD)                    &&
git checkout "$original"   "${quiet[@]}" &&
git merge -m "$msgmerge" "${mergeopts[@]}" "$newsha"
```

Before merge:

[image]

After merge:

[image]

Note that "design" branch tip wasn't affected at all, even being a local branch, thanks to the detached commit trick. Other than that, both commits (the removal and the merge) are regular commits, with suitable commit messages and parents. And "master" branch is clean of any undesired files.

Comment: Interesting approach. +1. I'll have to test it. By merging a detached HEAD, that would mean you won't really "see" (in a gitk) all those merges, right? Plus what happen when you repeat that merge several times? Will Git remember what has already being merged (especially when those detached HEAD have been purged?)

Comment: @VonC: Ok, maybe "detached commit" was a bit misleading: it is by all means a regular commit, the only difference is that it does not move `<branch>` tip.

Comment: And yes, since it is a regular commit, and a regular merge, you will see both, and they won't ever get pruned/purged. The "detached" thing was just a trick to leave local `<branch>`'s tip undisturbed.

Comment: @Vonc: or, to put it in other words: *it was only detached until it was used as a parent for a merge* (which happened instants later). And as a parent, it will live as long as **master** branch exists. I've updated the answer with 2 images...

Comment: What if the photohop directory existed on the master branch and there were one or more files that must remain and which the design branch must not change?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: no problem, it will still work as intended: files from `photoshop/*` are deleted only from the *design* branch, changes there are discarded; *master* branch is left untouched, so any files in that dir are kept.

Answer (score 10):

A few notes about `.gitignore`:

`.gitignore` is for ignoring files from the *working tree* to be **added** to *index* (staging area). So it is only effective when you use `git add <files>`, and it can still be overridden using `git add --force <files>`. It is meant just as a convenience to prevent unwanted files from being added, but it has **no effect on files inside the repository**

In your scenario, `.gitignore` is not needed, since *you* don't have any local `./photoshop` folder, so you will never have any photoshop files to add to your master branch. It wouldn't hurt, however, to create one just in case. And for the design team `.gitignore` is not welcome, since they *want* photoshop files to be added to their branch.

So, since merge deals with *committed data*, and `./photoshop` files are already inside the repository, your approach of using a a merge driver was correct.

The problem is... by default a **merge driver is only triggered in case of *conflicts***. And, since `master` branch does not have any `./photoshop` folder or files, *there are no conflicts at all*, they are cleanly merged. So your merge driver also had no effect, regardless of your path patterns (by the way, your 2nd one, `photoshop/`, was the correct one). I don't know if git merge can be configured to trigger a merge driver even for non-conflicting files, but it's worth googling for.

My answer is not a true solution to your problem. I just hoped to shed some light on the subject, explaining why your attempts using merge driver and .gitignore have failed. I suggest reading more about (configuring) merge drivers. Also *submodules* is worth investigating.

**UPDATE**

[Maybe my other answer will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10220276/624066):

```
Usage: git-strip-merge [git-merge options] [-M <commitmsg>] <branch> FILE...
```

[git-strip-merge](https://github.com/MestreLion/git-tools/blob/master/git-strip-merge)

Comment: +1 for the effort and comments. Although you do realize that the OP hasn't been seen on SO for the last 18 months, right? Hopefully, it can give ideas to others.

Comment: @VonC: yes, I do realize this is an ancient question, and probably no one will read/care. But, still, SO is nice as a reference site, and others (or even myself) might stumble on this issue in the future, just like I did now.

Comment: Well done anyway. And I *always* read for the past 3 years and an half. And care.

Comment: I cared, because I was wondering whether you could control what gets merged via .gitignore.

Comment: @MestreLion You answered 21 months after I posted the question, so it's only fair that I wait another 27 months to accept your detailed answer :) Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: @FelipeKoch: StackOverflow, the joy of necromancers since 2008 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a `.gitignore` file in your `master` branch, to ignore any `photopshop` directory content ?
Then a merge from design to `master` shouldn't add that new directory in `master`.

If this works, you still needs a merge driver, but this time to manage the content of the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Or you could just put .gitignore in your $HOME (i.e., outside your rails directory) and enjoy :)

Comment: @rmk: very true, but it could be interesting to have this setting (ignoring '`photoshop`' in '`master`' branch) pushed from repo to repo.

Comment: It is not accepting the merge: error: Untracked working tree file 'public/photoshop/photoshop/bar.psd' would be overwritten by merge.  Aborting

Comment: @Felipe: Could you reset your master branch to a cleaned content first (do a git stash first if you have work in progress not yet committed): `git clean -n -d .` or `git checkout -f master` (as in http://railsdog.com/blog/2008/08/untracked-working-tree-file-blah-would-be-overwritten-by-merge). And then do the merge (note: the updated `.gitignore` file should be committed first, before attempting the merge)

Comment: That's what I did. My current working tree is clean. The git clean indicated that log/, tmp/ and test/integration would be removed.

Comment: @Felipe: strange, maybe the `gitignore` is not compatible with the merge in this case.

Comment: Yes, I did another test on a temporary folder and gitignore is ignored during merge...

Comment: @Felipe: good to know. I am still looking for an option which might make a merge conforming to local `.gitignore` directives.

Comment: .gitignore by design does not deal with data inside a repo. The suggested .gitignore file on his master branch will have no effect. See my answer for more details.