# Git - Ignore files during merge

Tags: git, merge, push, ignore, repository

I have a repo called `myrepo` on the remote `beanstalk` server.

I cloned it to my local machine. Created two additional branches: `staging` and `dev`.
Pushed these branches to remote as well.

Now:

```
 local                   remote                   server
 --------------------------------------------------------  
 master  ==> Pushes to  `master`  ==> deployed to `prod`
 staging ==> Pushes to  `staging` ==> deployed to `staging`
 dev     ==> Pushes to  `dev`     ==> deployed to `dev`
```

I have a file called `config.xml` which is different on each branch.

I want to ignore this file only during merges. But I want this to be included when I checkout or commit from/to the repo branch.

The reason I want this is, we have a deploy script that pulls (checkout) the specific branch and deploys on the respective servers. So we need `config.xml` file of that specific branch go into the specific server as indicated above when deployed.

I guess `.gitignore` wont work. What are the other options? Note that the ignored file should be part of checkout and commit, which is important. it should be ignored only during merges.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: ignore some files during a merge (keep some files restricted to one branch)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868491/git-ignore-some-files-during-a-merge-keep-some-files-restricted-to-one-branch)

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? git attributes are only useful for the case where the file has conflicts between the branches being merged, so its not always enough.

Comment: did you look into symbolic (not followed by git) or even hard links to the rescue?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I ended up finding git `attributes`. Trying it. Working so far. Did not check all scenarios yet. But it should be the solution.

[Merge Strategies - Git attributes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_merge_strategies)

Comment: but I found this [git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html#Merge-Strategies](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html#Merge-Strategies)

Comment: Here is the correct link for the merge strategies section of the git attributes docs: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_merge_strategies

Comment: Found this well explained in an article https://medium.com/@porteneuve/how-to-make-git-preserve-specific-files-while-merging-18c92343826b

Comment: This seems to be a problem if there are no conflicts? Files will still be merged?

Comment: @Brett, In fact, you can keep this file always conflicting on every branch, so you can avoid automatic merging because of there is no conflict.
For example, add one line to the file of every branch:
`<text>{branch_name}</text>`

Answer (score 182):

I got over this issue by using git merge command with the `--no-commit` option and then explicitly removed the staged file and ignore the changes to the file.
E.g.: say I want to ignore any changes to `myfile.txt` I proceed as follows:

```
git merge --no-ff --no-commit <merge-branch>
git reset HEAD myfile.txt
git checkout -- myfile.txt
git commit -m "merged <merge-branch>"
```

You can put statements 2 & 3 in a for loop, if you have a list of files to skip.

Comment: I'd add "--no-ff" if you want a file not be overwritten when merge happens in fast-forward strategy.

Comment: so what does `git reset HEAD myfile.txt` do exactly? How does it help with our goal here?

Comment: How do you put lines 2 and 3 in a loop?

Comment: @AndroidDev You can do something like this: `for i in \`ls myfile.txt myfile_2.txt\`; do echo $i; git reset HEAD $i && git checkout -- $i; done`

Comment: @Kid_Learning_C : `git reset HEAD myfile.txt` unstages the file (which was staged post `--no-commit` merging)

Comment: how about new files in merge-branch, how to avoid them being brought over by merge?

Answer (score 36):

**`.gitattributes`** - is a root-level file of your repository that defines the attributes for a subdirectory or subset of files.

You can specify the attribute to tell Git to use different merge strategies for a specific file. Here, we want to preserve the existing `config.xml` for our branch.
We need to set the `merge=foo` to `config.xml` in `.gitattributes` file.

`merge=foo` tell git to use our(current branch) file, if a merge conflict occurs.

1. Add a `.gitattributes` file at the root level of the repository
2. You can set up an attribute for confix.xml in the `.gitattributes` file

   ```
    <pattern> merge=foo
   ```

   Let's take an example for `config.xml`

   ```
    config.xml merge=foo
   ```
3. And then define a dummy `foo` merge strategy with:

   ```
    $ git config --global merge.foo.driver true
   ```

If you merge the `stag` form `dev` branch, instead of having the merge conflicts with the `config.xml` file, the stag branch's config.xml preserves at whatever version you originally had.

for more reference: [merge_strategies](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_merge_strategies)

Comment: But what if there is no conflict? How to always keep a certain file during merge?

Comment: @IgorYalovoy: If there is no conflict ... well, this is a little tricky as it actually works from hash IDs, but: if `config.xml` is *completely unchanged* from the merge base to either branch tip version, Git just takes the changed version, without looking at the `merge.ours.driver` setting. So you are correct to be concerned.

Comment: copy-paste from Git Docs: Merge Strategies - Git attributes. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15233458/3743145)

Comment: This method results in "merge commits" every time FYI.

Comment: "ours" appears to be an arbitrary name for the new strategy being introduced. I found this confusing, because `theirs` is a built-in merge strategy. But it seems that one can write `<pattern> merge=foo`, then `git config --global merge.foo.driver true`, and it will work the same way.

Comment: Adding a `.gitattributes` file to the `main` branch with `<filename-to-exclude> merge=ours`, then running `git config --global merge.ours.driver true` worked great. The config file in `dev` was not merged into the config file in `main`. Unfortunately, during the merge the `.gitattributes` file was deleted (because it did not exist in `dev`)! How do avoid this? Just add the same `.gitattributes` file to `dev`? Would the `ours` value cause a conflict?

Comment: Ended up: Created `.gitattributes` in `dev` branch according to above comment, add, commit, push to `dev`. Checkout `main`, `git merge dev`, push to `main`. This successfully ignored the file in question.

Answer (score 13):

**Example:**

1. You have two branches: `master`, `develop`
2. You created file in `develop` branch and want to ignore it while merging

**Code:**

```
git config --global merge.ours.driver true
git checkout master
echo "path/file_to_ignore merge=ours" >> .gitattributes
git merge develop
```

You can also ignore files with same extension

for example all files with `.txt` extension:

```
echo "*.txt merge=ours" >> .gitattributes
```

Comment: This is working only in situation where have a conflict!

Answer (score 9):

You could start by using `git merge --no-commit`, and then edit the merge however you like i.e. by unstaging `config.xml` or any other file, then commit.  I suspect you'd want to automate it further after that using hooks, but I think it'd be worth going through manually at least once.

Comment: Does `git attributes` offer any straight solution? I am not able to understand this.  http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Merge-Strategies

Answer (score 8):

As commented by many it should be noted that the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15233458/2116560) and the copies of it (using a custom merge strategy for a specific file or files) **only works in cases where there would be actual merge conflicts**.

2 simple cases that would not result in merge conflicts and therefore commits getting merged:

- You have a `config.xml` file in a feature branch and not in master. You want to exclude it during merge
- Your `config.xml` file in both branches are based off the same commit. New code is added to the file in feature.

---

Either use `merge --no-commit` as demonstrated by [unmesh-gurjar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16455853/2116560) or simply cherry-pick invidiual commits into master. The latter being rather cumbersome of course and coming with a couple of other pitfalls (new SHA1 IDs etc.)

Comment: What is the resolution to this?

Comment: @Gabriel: The sad truth is there is no set-and-forget solution as simple as adding a file to a .gitignore afaia. You'd need to use one of the workarounds above (which they are imho) or unfortunately work with other VCSs.

Comment: You could also consider the accepted answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14369378/how-to-make-git-ignore-a-directory-while-merging (shows a variation using `merge --no-commit`)

Answer (score 5):

You could use `.gitignore` to keep the `config.xml` out of the repository, and then use a [post commit hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to upload the appropriate `config.xml` file to the server.

Comment: I know thats kind of hack. I am trying to find a clean solution. What about git `attributes`. Any idea how it works? I am not able to understand this.  http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Merge-Strategies

Comment: I have not heard of these, I'm trying to apply the merge=ours attribute, looks promising.

Comment: Git attributes are awesome! You can even tell git how to diff non-text files, so you could use pdf2text to diff PDFs!

Answer (score 3):

Here git-update-index - Register file contents in the working tree to the index.

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <PATH_OF_THE_FILE>
```

Example:-

> `git update-index --assume-unchanged somelocation/pom.xml`

Comment: That's nice when pushing but still complains when pulling might overwrite the file.

Comment: have you tried to add your file entry in .gitignore file. @Rolf

Answer (score 1):

Consider using git hooks:

> After you run a successful git checkout, the post-checkout hook runs; you can use it to set up your working directory properly for your project environment. This may mean moving in large binary files that you don’t want source controlled, auto-generating documentation, or something along those lines.

Source: [https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#:~:text=After%20you%20run,along%20those%20lines](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#:%7E:text=After%20you%20run,along%20those%20lines).

You can put these files in a separate directory that if necessary, can be chosen to exclude from the repository through `.gitignore`.

Based on the name of the branch that is being switched to, the script from the `post-checkout` hook can then take the correct files (could be in subdirs) for that branch and copy (overwriting) them to the correct locations. These individual files that are branch-specific, need to be in `.gitignore`.

Example of `post-checkout` script in `.git/hooks`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

BRANCH=`git reflog | awk 'NR==1{ print $8; exit }'`

cp "./configs/$BRANCH/config.json" "./config.json"

exit 0
```