# Always keep deleted state of file during merge

Tags: git, merge, ignore, gitattributes

I have a special case of [ignoring files during merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232000/git-ignore-files-during-merge).

Suppose I have two branches: **A** and **B**.
**A** contains files *a.txt* and *b.txt*.
**B** contains file *a.txt* but **not** *b.txt*. And that's the way it should be.

Now I want to merge the changes in **A** into **B**, i.e., update *a.txt*. However, during the merge I always get a conflict:

`CONFLICT (modify/delete): b.txt deleted in HEAD and modified in development. Version development of b.txt left in tree.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.`

How can I set up `.gitattributes` so that **B**'s version of the file (i.e., deleted) is being kept, i.e., *b.txt* ignored during merge?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  The attributes you can set in `.gitattributes` apply only to what I call *low level* conflicts, but "modify/delete" is what I call a *high level* conflict.

It's worth mentioning, though, that just because **A** *has* `b.txt` and **B** does not, does not guarantee you will get *always* get a modify/delete conflict.  What kind of conflict you get—if any—depends as well on the *merge base* commit.  The branch **A** resolves to the tip commit of that branch, and likewise for **B**, but `git merge` does not use only those inputs.  It finds a third input:

```
          o--o--...--o   <-- A
         /
...--o--*
         \
          o--...--o   <-- B
```

Each round `o` represents some commit.  The commit marked `*`, which is where the two branches split apart originally—and hence, *right now*, the first place they come back togther—is the current merge base of the two branch tips.

You now run `git checkout B && git merge A`.  Git compares commit `*` to the tip of **A** and finds `b.txt` modified since `*`.  Git compares `*` to the tip of **B** and finds `b.txt` removed.  This is what produces the high level conflict, about which `.gitattributes` does nothing.  So you must merge this file manually and then commit the result:

```
          o--...--o   <-- A
         /         \
...--o--o           \
         \           \
          o--...--o---o   <-- B
```

Because this is a true merge, the new commit has two parents.  The first parent is the previous tip of **B** (the straight line across the bottom) and the second parent is the previous and still current tip of **A** (going up and left).  No big deal so far; but now let's make new commits on both **A** and **B**:

```
          o--...--o--o--o   <-- A
         /         \
...--o--o           \
         \           \
          o--...--o---o--o   <-- B
```

If we now do that `git checkout B && git merge A` again, Git will find a new merge base, by searching backwards from both tips as before.  The first commit that's reachable from both branch tips will be the merge base—but this time, that's a commit on the top row, specifically the one just before the last merge:

```
          o--...--*--o--o   <-- A
         /         \
...--o--o           \
         \           \
          o--...--o---o--o   <-- B
```

Git will now diff commit `*` against the current tips of **A** and **B**.

Since presumably **B** still lacks `b.txt`, Git will conclude that `*`-to-ours removes the file.  If you haven't touched `b.txt` in the two new commits on **A**, though, `*`-to-theirs doesn't change it.  There will be no high level conflict: "unchanged in **A**, removed in **B**" resolves to "remove in merge".