# Skip a file in GIT merge between branches

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Is it possible to skip a file during the merge between GIT branches? I tried following gitignore, gitattributes but did not help

Comment: How's gitattributes not working? Seems it is the way to go, based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/15233458/395202 .  I would consider it is a duplicate unless  you show us how the approach does not work for you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git - Ignore files during merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232000/git-ignore-files-during-merge)

Answer (score 0):

If by "skipping" a file in the merge you mean "letting this file as it was before merging", you can let the file conflict when the merge occurs, then tell git you want the pre-merge version of the file, with (according to your context, but probably)
`git checkout --ours your.file`
then don't forget to
`git add your.file`
and finish merging as you would normally.