# How to maintain seperate files in dev and main branches and sub branches github

Tags: git, github, branching-and-merging, git-flow

**Question:** When merging `dev` into `main`, how do I keep them `.ebextensions` and `.elasticbeanstalk` commited on their respective branches but never overwriting each other during merges?

**Requirement:**
I wish to checkout new topic branches from `dev` and merge them back into `dev`, so these topic branches will need the same `.ebextensions` and `.elasticbeanstalk` folders to *come* with them.

**Landscape:**
Working with Github on Flask project for Elastic beanstalk.

I have two primary `branches`

- main
- dev

I have `dev` set up for one Elastic beanstalk environment, and `main` set up in another. This means I have **two different** versions of the `.ebextensions` and `.elasticbeanstalk` folders.

```
.
├── application.py
├── .ebextensions
├── .ebignore
├── .elasticbeanstalk
├── .gitignore
├── main.py
└── .vscode
```

I keep messing up the files and having to write them back in locally and push to remote again to fix them.

Having read about a third of `git-scm.com's` book so I think the solution will involve `"onbranch:" includeIf` but the [example](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_conditional_includes) is hard to follow.

Surely I've missed something, it can't be an uncommon requirement.

Comment: It's not obvious, but this is in fact a [Frequently Asked Question](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#How_do_I_tell_Git_to_ignore_tracked_files.3F), whose answer is really "you can't do that". Come up with some other approach: e.g., don't store those files under *those names* at all. Instead, when you *deploy* a release, copy or rename the appropriate set of files into place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**When you do actions in Git, nearly all of them only add data to the Git database** was a line I read but didn't apply when trying to resolve this issue.

Thanks to @torek for clarifying.

My summary solution is **store all the files**

So now my file structure looks like

```
.
├── application.py
├── .ebextensions-dev
├── .ebextensions-main
├── .ebignore
├── .elasticbeanstalk-dev
├── .elasticbeanstalk-main
├── .gitignore
├── main.py
└── .vscode
```

When I want to deploy the application to the `dev` Elastic beanstalk environment:

1. Remove the `-dev` from the end of the `.ebextensions-dev` and `.elasticbeanstalk-dev` folder names.

```
files='.elasticbeanstalk .ebextensions'
x='-dev'
for i in $files; do
    mv $i$x $i
done;
```

2. Run `eb deploy`
3. Add the `-dev` back onto the end of the `.ebextensions` and `.elasticbeanstalk` folder names.

```
files='.elasticbeanstalk .ebextensions'
x='-dev'
for i in $files; do
    mv $i $i$x
done;
```

vica-versa for `main`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you already found a possible workaround, but I'd like to propose an alternative solution in which you set Git to never overwrite specific files.

This can be done by creating a .gitattributes file with a pattern matching your files, and then creating a dummy merge strategy.

A more in-depth discussion for this approach can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49358531/19128226), with some more information [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_merge_strategies).

I believe that in your case you could do something along the lines of

```
git config --global merge.ours.driver true
echo ".ebextensions/* merge=ours" >> .gitattributes
echo ".elasticbeanstalk/* merge=ours" >> .gitattributes
```

Please do note that I'm not sure if passing a hole directory with a wildcard will work, though I imagine it should be possible.