# Ignore file to be merged with master

Tags: git

I have 2 branches, dev and master.
In dev, there is a file that I don't want in master, but I still need to track it. However I cannot get git to ignore this file when merging from dev to master.

I use 2 machines, one where I commit to dev and other where I merge. The sequence I did is the following:

**1. Machine 1: Create and push .gitattributes**

Create a .gitattributes file with:

```
path/to/file.py merge=ignore
```

Commit file:

```
git add .gitattributes
git commit -m "adding .gitattributes"
git push
```

**2. Machine 2: Merge**

```
git config --global merge.ignore.driver true
git pull
git checkout master
git merge dev
# file is neither in master nor in dev, will e commited in the next step
ls path/to/file.py
# ls: cannot access 'path/to/file.py': No such file or directory
```

**3. Machine 1: Commit the file to be ignored on merge**

```
git add path/to/file.py
git commit -m "adding file.py"
git push
```

**4. Machine 2: despite .gitattributes, git merge does not ignore file.py**

```
git merge dev --no-commit
# file is not ignored and ready to be merged to master...
ls path/to/file.py
# path/to/file.py
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232000/git-ignore-files-during-merge) was suggested as duplicate. You may see from commands above that I'm doing basically what is suggested in the answers there, but it does not work, so I keep trying to find the solution. Also, Git hooks mentioned in the same place are not portable (repo is used by both Windows and Mac users).

Comment: You cannot ignore a file that is tracked in git. Even if a file matches a pattern in your `.gitignore` file, when you add it to your repository explicitly you are telling git "do not ignore this file".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git - Ignore files during merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232000/git-ignore-files-during-merge)

Comment: Hi @EugeneSh. Thanks for the link - but I think the accepted answer does basically what I do.. Or not?

Comment: @larsks, thanks, the issue is that I still need to track the file in the dev branch, so I guess .gitignore is not an option.

Comment: It has a bunch of other answers. I guess if nothing works for you, then you are out of luck. Personally I'd simply merge with `--no-commit` and manually remove the file from staging.

Comment: @EugeneSh - sure, I was just hoping for more automated solution that wouldn't require me explaining this to everybody and remembering it forever. Some of the  other answers suggest git hooks, but I think that's not portable.