# Git: specifying a git merge strategy "ours" in gitattribute for a whole folder (or just disable merge errors on specific folder?)

Tags: git, git-merge, git-bash

I need to exclude the `dist/` folder from merging errors, I don't care if it is `theirs`, `ours` or other strategy but I need to keep it in the revision control since this is the way to deploy to Heroku. `.gitattributes` script seems to be the way to go. But I can't seem to make this work.

I read this [canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093540/tell-git-to-use-ours-merge-strategy-on-specific-files) and this [similiar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093540/tell-git-to-use-ours-merge-strategy-on-specific-files) but can't find out what I'm doing wrong.

My `.gitattributes` config:

```
* text=auto
dist/ merge=keepMine
```

The relevant part of my  `.git/config` :

```
[merge "keepMine"]
    name = always keep mine dist during merge
    driver = keepMine.sh %O %A %B
```

and `keepMine.sh` (in my project root folder, no the folder isn't in the path, but copying to a folder in the path didn't help and isn't a good solution since the script should be part of revision control so all developers would get it):

```
# copied as is from the SO answer
# I want to keep MY version when there is a conflict
# Nothing to do: %A (the second parameter) already contains my version
# Just indicate the merge has been successfully "resolved" with the exit status
exit 0
```

**EDIT:** Also tried `git config merge.keepMine.driver true` as suggested in one of the SO answers above. Didn't work.

But I'm still getting merge errors (If I create them) for example in `dist/styles/sdkasl.main.css` for example.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm at best a git novice, but I've been following this question for the past few days hoping to see a solution to your issue. Did you get it resolved? If not, perhaps [How to make git ignore a directory while merging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14369378/how-to-make-git-ignore-a-directory-while-merging) can help?

Comment: @ChronoKitsune this is another issue, I don't want to do a manual merge (in which that answer would help) but an automated merge..

Comment: I just tried what you described and it works for me. Could you please update your question with the output from a failing merge? E.g. GIT_TRACE=2 git merge ...

Comment: Please post the output of `git check-attr --all dist/styles/sdkasl.main.css`

Comment: That's an oldy question, not sure I even have those files anymore.. I'll check. just for the sake of learning

Comment: you don't you keep this directory as a git [submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)? what you are trying to do cause alot of history issues in git in case you need to check diffs or revert some commits in the future.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `dist/**` in the *.gitattributes* file?

Comment: `.gitattributes` patterns follow the same convention as `.gitignore` so a folder would include everything in that folder and below.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_merge_strategies) isn't great in this one.

> You can also use Git attributes to tell Git to use different merge strategies for specific files in your project.

Sounds great! We can read about *merge strategies* [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies) and there's one called *ours* that'd be really helpful.

Unfortunately the next line crushes that dream. Emphasis mine.

> One very useful option is to tell Git to not try to merge specific files **when they have conflicts**, but rather to use your side of the merge over someone else’s.

Sadly for us, if the changes to `dist/` in `feature` don't conflict with `master` then they'll be merged into `dist/` on `master`. The second [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22085876/1281548) to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14093540/1281548) you linked above discusses this.

I'd suggest a [post merge hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_other_client_hooks) that resets `dist/` to some pristine state.