# Git - prevent a development directory from being added on merge

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm a programmer who's more familiar with higher-level programming languages such as C# or Python, but I've recently started working deeper into the intricacies of Git. Context: I'm developing a game, and I have a `development` branch with a specific `'Development'` directory which will not be pushed to `master` in a merge, for the sake of keeping `master` clean.

I came to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14369793/5402030) which nearly does the job; however, this method, while it won't *commit* the changes to the directory, **still creates it on the `master` branch**, meaning that after every merge, I would still need to go back and delete the files manually.

I'm setting up an alias `git publish` to automate this task, which I'll post here for completeness:

```
[alias]
    publish = "!f(){ git checkout master \
        && git merge --no-commit --no-ff development \
        && git reset -- Assets/Development/ \
        && git commit \
        && git push; };f"
```

I'd like to know, **is there any way I can prevent `Assets/Development/` from being created on `master`?**

Comment: Why can't you just put it in .gitignore?

Comment: Why can't you put the folder outside the directory containing your repository, assuming there really be no need to version it?

Comment: @antlersoft - Wouldn't .gitignore also ignore changes on other branches? The release branch is the only one I want to leave the Development assets off of.

Comment: @Tim - Because I'm in a Unity project, and in order for unity to see the assets I'm using to develop, they need to be in the Assets folder.

Comment: @BHustus - .gitignore is versioned, so you can have a different version in each of your branches; the development branch version can ignore the folder you want to ignore.  If you merge from another branch to development, the .gitignore will fail you though.

Comment: Wow, .gitignore is versioned? I never knew that. But I want to do most of my merging into development. It's not until I merge into release that I want to ignore the Development directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Side note: fiddling with `.gitignore` won't help, because of the nature of `.gitignore`, which is not really "files to ignore", but rather "files to suppress certain complaints about, and/or to feel free to destroy in some cases".  (This is not meant to say that you should not adjust `.gitignore` for other reasons, just that it won't help with this merge issue, because you really *do* want those files versioned in the development branch.)

#### Your existing workaround (and ways to perhaps improve it)

One trick is basically what you are doing now: do the merge (with `--no-commit`), then strip out the stuff you did not want.

The strip-out step is this:

```
git reset -- Assets/Development/
```

This uses the `--mixed` (default, and forced upon you when giving paths) form of `git reset`, which sets (or "resets", really) the index to match the specified tree for the specified path(s).  Here the path is `Assests/Development/`, i.e., everything within that subdirectory.  The specified tree is, well, not specified—so it defaults to `HEAD`, or rather, the tree for `HEAD`.  `HEAD` is the current commit on the current branch, which is of course `master` since we just checked that out; and `master` does not contain `Assets/Development/` at all, so the re-set index now no longer has that sub-tree.

In short, because `Assets/Development/` is not in `HEAD`, this undoes the `git add`s that `git merge` did on everything in `Assets/Development`.  The problem is that while this removes the entries from the *index*, it leaves them in the *work tree*.

One might try `git reset --hard -- Assets/Development/` but git won't do that: you cannot specify a reset mode when giving paths.  That leaves three more obvious options, though:

- add `rm -r Assets/Development` (just before or just after the `git reset`, or even after the `commit` step)

  This removes the files, so with them gone from the index and work-tree, you can commit and be done.
- use `git rm -rf Assets/Development/` (in place of the `git reset`)

  This removes the index entries *and* removes the work-tree files (and directory), so you can commit and be done.
- use `git clean` after committing.  This may do more than you want.

The main thing is, you *may* only have to do this once, not repeatedly.  It depends on what changes you make along the way.

#### More about merge

When you run `git merge <commit>`, git first finds the *merge base*.

The merge base is defined as the **L**owest **C**ommon **A**ncestor (LCA) in the commit graph between two nodes in the graph.  The two nodes are your current commit—in this case, the tip of branch `master`—and the commit you give to `git merge`, which in this case is the tip commit of branch `development`.  The definition of LCA requires a bit of graph theory, but loosely speaking, it's the "nearest" commit that is on *both* commit histories.

To see how this works, it helps to draw part of the commit graph.  Here we have `master` and `development` as two branch tips, with the two branch structures (chains of commits) eventually joining up:

```
... <- o <- * <- o <- ... <- o     <-- master
             \
              o <- o <- ... <- o   <-- development
```

The commit marked `*` is the merge base: it's the point where `development` and `master` rejoin, and commit `*` and every earlier commit is on *both* branches, rather than just being on one.

What `merge` does at this point is to generate two diffs: one from `*` to the tip of the current commit (the tip commit on `master`), and one from `*` to the other, target, commit (the tip of `development`).

In `master` you have some (probably not too many) changes since `*`, and in `development` you have a bunch of changes, including the addition of `Assets/Development/`.

The `merge` command combines the changes, which include adding the unwanted directory.  When all done, git makes a new commit (the `--no-ff` step guarantees this; if the merge base commit `*` were the tip of `master`, which is not what we drew but is possible on the first merge, git would try to do a label fast-forward instead of making an actual merge).

The result is a graph that now looks more like this (I'm going to stop drawing in the left-pointing arrows, just be aware that history goes leftward, i.e., later commits point back to earlier ones):

```
...--o--*--o-...-o---o   <-- master
         \          /
          o--o-...-o     <-- development
```

Now you continue to develop on `development`, making more new commits.  Let's replace `*` with `o` since it's no longer a special case.

```
...--o--o--o-...-o---o       <-- master
         \          /
          o--o-...-o--o--o   <-- development
```

and at some point you decide to merge again, so you check out `master` and tell `git merge` to find the (new) tip of `development` and calculate the merge base.

The merge base is, again (and a bit loosely), the first commit that's on *both* branches.  Let's find it: is it the same as before?  Start at the tips of both `master` and `development` and work backwards from each, coloring nodes with two different colors.  As soon as a node gets *both* colors, that's a common ancestor.  The one *closest to the tips* is the "lowest", i.e., is the merge base.

I can't draw colors, but if you do the exercise yourself, you will see that it's this node:

```
...--o--o--o-...-o---o       <-- master
         \          /
          o--o-...-*--o--o   <-- development
```

The node now marked `*` is reachable from `master` (by following the second parent down-and-left), and from `development` (by following the chain left).  It is the closest such node, so it is the merge base.

Git now diffs the merge base `*` against the two tips.  There should be few if any changes to the tip of `master` (basically only whatever was picked up from the `o` nodes between the previous merge base and the new tip of `master`), and whatever changes you have made to the `development` branch since the last merge.

If those changes affect existing files in `Assets/Development`, those changes will cause a merge conflict:

```
CONFLICT (modify/delete): Assets/Development/foo deleted in HEAD
 and modified in development. Version development of
 Assets/Development/foo left in tree.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Note that you don't need the `--no-commit` for these.

If those changes add *new* files in `Assets/Development/`, on the other hand, merge will happily add them to the commit you are about to make, so you do need `--no-commit` to avoid adding any such files.

You can again use `git rm -rf` to just toss any conflicts and/or added files, if necessary.

Comment: *Whistles* I'll be honest with you, when I asked this question I didn't expect a total git merge lesson! This is great. I'll try out the solutions at once. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm doing it wrong, but when I tried the first two options - reluctant to choose `git clean` because of the note that it might do more than I intended - they didn't work. The files, while not committed, remained present and had to be manually deleted.

Comment: Second thought - scratch that - the `rm -rf` in place of `reset` worked, though `rm -r` alongside `reset` didn't. Thanks. :D

Comment: Yes, `git rm -r` fails because it worries about losing work, so you have to `git rm -rf`.  (Non-git `rm -r` would not complain, generally.)  And I have started on the merge text for my git+mercurial book so I'm fussing around with all this lately... :-) )

Comment: Well, I'm glad the circumstances worked out so well! also: I guess I misinterpreted the difference between `rm -r` and `git rm -r` - I figured the `git` was implied!