# How to manage resource file changes between a development branch and master branch

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

I am trying to understand the best way to manage my resource files between two branches while merging new features from dev into master.

**This is what I did so far:**

1. Created a **Dev** branch from my **Master** branch.
2. Changed the resource file strings in my **Dev** branch (changed end points / folder locations) to use for testing.
3. Added some minor feature in my **Dev** branch.
4. Tried to merge the feature from my **Dev** branch into my **master** branch<-- issue occurs because I don't want my resource file changes to be merged.

So how do I go about managing my resource files in my dev branch without overwriting resource files in my master branch on merge? I am using TFS and this is the first time I have been trying to utilize different deploy environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As workaround, you can try to reset some specified files after git merge.

```
git checkout master    
git merge --no-commit --no-ff development
git reset -- /path/to/folder # revert updates from path
git commit
```

For details , you can refer to following tickets:

- [How to make git ignore a directory while merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14369378/how-to-make-git-ignore-a-directory-while-merging)
- [Git - Ignore files during merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232000/git-ignore-files-during-merge)