# How can I git pull --rebase but taking all remote changes?

Tags: git

I did `git fetch` and then `git pull --rebase`. It is trying to merge changes from the remote branch to my local branch. And there are some merge conflicts. So I did a `git reset --hard`.

My question is it is possible for me to ask git pull to take the remote change whenever there is a conflict?

Comment: Once can also fetch and then rebase manually (e.g. `git fetch` and `git rebase -X theirs origin/foo`)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

```
git pull --rebase -s recursive -X ours
```

But it doesn't work (I'm using 1.7.0.4), even though the manpage says it should.  I'm guessing this is due to the issue [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945344/selecting-merge-strategy-options-for-git-rebase).

Instead, you could use:

```
git pull -s recursive -X theirs
```

It works as expected, but you'll get a *merge* instead of a *rebase*.

Also - note 'ours', rather than 'theirs' when using --rebase.  From the git-rebase manpage:

> [CLIP]... a rebase merge works by replaying each commit from the working branch on top of the upstream branch. Because of this, when a merge conflict happens, the side reported as ours is the so-far rebased series, starting with upstream, and theirs is the working branch. In other words, the sides are swapped. ...[CLIP]

Comment: If I `git pull --rebase upstream devel`, wouldn't a `--strategy recursive` be redundant? The alternative would be the octopus merge strategy if I understand the manpages right, but it's only required if more than 2 branches are combined. In my case, there's only two (`upstream/devel` and `<local>/devel`, `<local>` being my working copy of `fork/devel` synced on Github). Thus, I would use `git pull --rebase --strategy-option theirs` if nothing speaks against it?

Comment: FWIW `git pull --rebase -s recursive -X ours` worked for me, thanks!