# How to keep the local file or the remote file during merge using Git and the command line?

Tags: git, merge, local

I know how to merge modification using vimdiff, but, assuming I just know that the entire file is good to keep or to throw away, how do I do that?

I don't want to open vimdiff for each of them, I change want a command that says 'keep local' or 'keep remote'.

E.G: I got a merge with files marked as changed because somebody opened it under windows, changing the EOL, and then commited. When merging, I want to just keep my own version and discard his.

I'm also interested in the contrary: I screwed up big time and want to accept the remote file, discarding my changes.

Answer (score 388, accepted):

You can as well do:

```
git checkout --theirs /path/to/file
```

to keep the remote file, and:

```
git checkout --ours /path/to/file
```

to keep local file.

Then `git add` them and everything is done.

**Edition:
Keep in mind that this is for a `merge` scenario. During a `rebase` `--theirs` refers to the branch where you've been working.**

Comment: I did this.. but nothing happens.. how do I know it is taking the correct file? I am using `git version 1.8.4` if that matters.

Comment: @RosdiKasim /path/to/file must be the path to your correct file. Your git version is ok.

Comment: why the inverse word use? I assume "theirs" would be remote file and "ours" would be my file

Comment: So it is, @LưuVĩnhPhúc

Comment: no, their meanings are reversed http://stackoverflow.com/q/2959443/995714 http://stackoverflow.com/q/29324812/995714 theirs would be my files and ours are the files in the remote branch

Comment: Well, this could be true during a rebase, but the question is for a merge

Comment: "Easy", yes. Intuitive? No.

Comment: I have been using Git daily for almost 3 years and I learn something new weekly

Comment: Both of these commands do nothing for my merge-conflicted files. I don't get an error or anything. Everything just stays the same.

Comment: `error: path 'data/.../client_id.txt' does not have our version` - Nope, not easy.

Comment: @Shadoninja , @Rosdi Kasim, in case it helps others who come across your comments above. I was also seeing the same thing, but you then need to resolve each conflict with `git add filename`. When you do that, the index shows the correct changes, i.e. no changes if you've chosen `--ours`

Comment: @VincentFourmond probably you were rebasing instead of merging

Comment: @WaitingforDev... Indeed. I think this would deserve a clear **bold** warning in the answer, please (and I'll change my -1 to +1 then).

Comment: Done @VincentFourmond

Comment: Thanks for rebase warning. That's exactly why using git is exhausting. The first thing I looked for was rebase scenario as someone who has had painful experiences.

Answer (score 147):

This approach seems more straightforward, avoiding the need to individually select each file:

```
# keep remote files
git merge --strategy-option theirs
# keep local files
git merge --strategy-option ours
```

or

```
# keep remote files
git pull -Xtheirs
# keep local files
git pull -Xours
```

Copied directly from:
[Resolve Git merge conflicts in favor of their changes during a pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697463/resolve-git-merge-conflict-accepting-their-changes)

Comment: Love this one. Specially if there's more than one file.

Comment: The question was for two different commands, but there's no description as to what these two do. What does each line do?

Comment: I went through at least five stackoverflow answers before finding this, which is what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @keflavich, if i am doing rebase from 1 branch to another, and l'd like to use this ```git merge --strategy-option theirs``` strategy, at which point should i put this command in? and is it temporary only? I'd like it to only keep effect in this rebase, not the future one.

Comment: found the answer, sorry did not realize this thread was merge only, i thought it was merge conflicts . https://stackoverflow.com/a/4273436/4582240

Comment: error: Merging is not possible because you have unmerged files  ... 8)

Answer (score 24):

`git checkout {branch-name} -- {file-name}`

This will use the file from the branch of choice.

I like this because `posh-git` autocomplete works great with this. It also removes any ambiguity as to which branch is remote and which is local.
And `--theirs` didn't work for me anyways.

Comment: No ambiguity, works for both {mine} and {theirs}, supports adding entire directories. **This should be the accepted answer.**

Answer (score 11):

For the line-end thingie, refer to `man git-merge`:

```
--ignore-space-change 
--ignore-all-space 
--ignore-space-at-eol
```

Be sure to add `autocrlf = false` and/or `safecrlf = false` to the windows clone (.git/config)

### Using git mergetool

If you configure a mergetool like this:

```
git config mergetool.cp.cmd '/bin/cp -v "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"'
git config mergetool.cp.trustExitCode true
```

Then a simple

```
git mergetool --tool=cp
git mergetool --tool=cp -- paths/to/files.txt
git mergetool --tool=cp -y -- paths/to/files.txt # without prompting
```

Will do the job

### Using simple git commands

In other cases, I assume

```
git checkout HEAD -- path/to/myfile.txt
```

should do the trick

**Edit** to do the reverse (because you screwed up):

```
git checkout remote/branch_to_merge -- path/to/myfile.txt
```

Comment: +1 for the tips, but not accepted butcause it's not what I asked for. I want something that work in all the cases, not just in the example cases. Plus "git checkout remote/branch_to_merge -- path/to/myfile.txt" won't work if you started your merge already: it will say that you are in the middle of a merge and will prevent you from doing so.

Comment: @e-satis: that's surprising. I would consider that a bug, since checkout with a path is not a regular checkout (and it doesn't affect HEAD). I'm gonna try it out now because I can't believe it

Comment: @e-satis: Soooo... I was right; `git checkout remote/branch_to_merge -- path/to/myfile.txt` works like a charm while resolving a merge conflict. (git 1.7.1)

Comment: Added a solution based on git mergetool now

Answer (score -1):

I asked the questions a day ago, very similar this quesiton but my questions is slightly different because it is something to do with a database, sqlite3.

but a manager on this site asked me to delete the quesition so I did delete it but he finally blocked me.

Anyway, the answer to my matter was "git checkout --their db.sqlite3"

Something related with databse, then just simply "git checkout --their db.sqlite3" not need to put path.

I leave this answer for someone who got same problem as me.

Comment: how is this different than the accepted answer? consider improving it to make relevant to the broader audience or removing it.

Comment: This answer is not different from accepted answer, but full of errors, and as the poster says, for his problem, "something to do with a database".