# Can I solve the merge conflicts easily by GUI(not bash)?

Tags: git

I'm using Git GUI,just now ,I want to merge a branch into master;however,git shows merge conflict tome. There are about 100+ files which have merge conflict.
My question is ,can I solve the merge conflicts easily by GUI(not bash);and can I user rebase in GUI?

Comment: your question is unclear whether you are going with merging or rebasing . however if you are going with merging you have to resolve all those conflicts before merging your branch with master . Also it doesn't matter if you are doing it using bash or the gui . either way , you have to face resolving conflicts in your local files.

Comment: hi,thanks, and I'm merging!

Comment: If i want to let the same-name files in branch-2 cover the files in branch-1;how should I  do in GUi?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best visual merge tool for Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137102/whats-the-best-visual-merge-tool-for-git)

Comment: Do you mean overwriting? That is a different thing. Merging 2 branches is more complicated. A normal "3 way merge" is based on the current state of the 2 branches and the most recent common point of divergence.

Comment: yes, i mean overwrting;how?

Comment: You can use the `theirs` strategy in the first place to always take the new version of a conflicted hunk, or you can use `git mergetool` and select this resolution manually. If mergetool doesn't have a (good) configured gui tool, you'll have to find a suitable one and configure it. since you don't like the shell, and haven't said what you _are_ using, I can't tell you exactly how to do either of these things.

Comment: Is this what you are asking? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650215/how-to-keep-the-local-file-or-the-remote-file-during-merge-using-git-and-the-com