# How can I git push all changes to origin master without merging?

Tags: git

git-2.16.2 on linux

git novice, so please bear with....

I cloned a repo, changed several files and now I want to push that to the origin master.  I do not want to merge anything, I want git to take all the changes I made without merging.

I believe I still have to to the git pull --rebase.  And I know there will be conflicts.  But is there a way to bypass the merge piece of this and just push all my changes back to the origin master without merging (after git add, git commit of c) ?

Comment: Do you intend to actually throw away the changes that were pushed by someone else on your remote? If not, you need to either rebase or merge, and resolve the conflicts, there's no way around it. If you do want to discard those changes on the remote, `gut push --force` is indeed what you want.

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is

```
git push --force
```

and everyone will tell you not to do that. That is, if you ever work together with someone on a repository (or actially a branch). This is because you are [rewriting history](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History).

If this is your own repository ( i think it is), it will be no problem.

If you want to do it "properly" you would have to do a merge, and then use only changes from local, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650215/how-to-keep-the-local-file-or-the-remote-file-during-merge-using-git-and-the-com#12025832). This way you preserve your history, and achieve the same result.

Comment: So --force will clobber anyone else's changes that I would have otherwise had to merge with ?

Comment: Yeah that's right. It literally forces the remote branch to be the same as the local branch. No matter what is there now.

Answer (score 2):

If the state of origin has changed since you cloned (e.g. person B has pushed to it), you can't just push your changes without destroying Person B's changes. Instead you should put your local changes on their own branch "new", pull Person B's changes into your master branch, then rebase your "new" branch onto the end of master. Then push it all back.

Comment: I don't need to do this right now but want to be ready if someone else pushes changes (even though I told them not to and would clobber those changes if they did).

Answer (score 1):

Git doesn't push *changes*, but rather *commits*.  That's because Git doesn't *store* changes either.

Every commit holds a full, complete snapshot of all of its files.  That's the *data* part of a commit.  Every commit also holds some *metadata*, such as who made it (name and email address), when, and why (the log message).  You can *view* a commit as changes, by comparing the snapshot to the previous commit's snapshot, but it's still a full snapshot.

Every commit has its own unique hash ID.  That hash ID means *that* commit: never any other commit, and no other Git repository anywhere can use that commit hash ID for any *other* commit.  Every Git repository that has *this* commit uses *that* hash ID for it.  (Which is why commit hash IDs are so big and ugly: they have to be unique!)

Meanwhile, inside the metadata for each commit, a commit holds the raw hash ID of some earlier or *parent* commit.  We say that this commit *points to* its parent.  If we draw a diagram of several commits, we see that they tend to become backwards-looking, linear chains:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where `H` is the *latest* or *last* commit.  It has some big ugly hash ID, which I've just called `H`, and commit `H` contains the actual hash ID of earlier commit `G`, which contains the hash ID of yet-earlier commit `F`, and so on.  These backwards chains make it easy for Git to *show* you a commit as a set of changes, which is much smaller (and more useful) than just showing you the entire snapshot every time.

What a *branch name* does in Git is that it lets you—and Git—quickly find this *last commit.*  I'm going to stop drawing the internal arrows as arrows (because of laziness) but keep drawing *branch names* as arrows:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

The *name* `master` contains the hash ID of the *last commit* `H`.

> I cloned a repo, changed several files and now I want to push that to the origin master.

Technically, you cloned the repo—which got you all their *commits*—and made you your own name `master`.  Your clone also remembered the hash ID of the last commit in *their* master, under your name `origin/master`, which we can draw like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

(This `HEAD` thing is how Git remembers which *branch name* you're using.)

When you made a new commit, it got a new, unique hash ID.  Let's just call this `I` for short:

```
...--G--H   <-- origin/master
         \
          I   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Note how your `master` now points to commit `I`, rather than `H`.  But you can still find `H` in two ways: `I` points back to `H`, and `origin/master` points directly to `H`.

Meanwhile, in *their* repository, perhaps someone has added a new commit or two:

```
...--G--H--J--K   <-- master
```

Remember, this is *their* repository (and their `master`), not yours.

When you run `git push origin master`, your Git calls up their Git.  Your Git tells them you have commit `I` and you'd like to give it to them.  Your Git tells them `I`'s parent is `H` and they say *ok, I already have that commit, just give me `I`*.  You send over `I` to them:

```
          I   [your commit]
         /
...--G--H--J--K   <-- master
```

It doesn't matter whether we draw `I` above or below, or draw it more branch-ily as:

```
          I   [your commit]
         /
...--G--H
         \
          J--K   <-- master
```

as long as we draw in all the relevant commits and their connections.

Now your Git asks them—their Git—to set *their* `master` to point to commit `I`, which you both now have.  *If they obey this polite request*, they will have:

```
          I   <-- master
         /
...--G--H--J--K
```

They *won't be able to find commits `J-K` any more*, because their Git *finds* the commits using their branch name.  That finds `I`, which leads back to `H` and then `G` and so on, but never forwards.

If you use `git push --force`, you change your polite request into a command: *Set your `master`!*  If they obey, they'll lose commits `J-K`.

#### What should you do about this?

What you will need, *if they have these commits*, is some way of sending your commit(s) so that they don't lose *theirs*.

You have several options.  One is to use `git merge origin/master` to *combine* your work with theirs.  The other is to use `git rebase`, which is more complicated.

#### Merging

To merge, use `git fetch` to make sure your own Git is up to date with theirs, then use `git merge origin/master`.<sup>1</sup>  This makes a new *merge commit*, which I'll draw in as `M`:

```
          I-----M   <-- master (HEAD)
         /     /
...--G--H--J--K   <-- origin/master
```

What makes a merge commit a merge is that it points back to *more than one parent*.  The two parents here are commits `I` and `K`.  If you now have your Git call up their Git and send your `master`, your Git will offer them commit `M`.  They'll take `M`.  Since `M` has two parents, your Git will offer `I` and `K`.  They have `K` but not `I`,<sup>2</sup> so they'll take `I` too, and your Git will offer `H`.  They have `H` so they'll just take `M` and `I` in the end.

Then, your Git will ask them to set their `master` to point to `M`.  That won't *lose* anything, so they'll probably accept this request.  Your own Git will now update your own `origin/master`—your memory of their `master`—accordingly.

---

<sup>1</sup>If you really like `git pull`, you can use `git pull` to *combine* the `git fetch` step with the `git merge` step.  All `git pull` does is run both commands.  This robs you of the opportunity to insert Git commands *between* the two commands, and for Git newbies, I find this makes things more confusing, so I prefer to keep these as separate commands.

<sup>2</sup>They might still have `I` from your earlier attempt, or not, depending on *their* Git version ... and whether you made an attempt after all.  If they do have `I`, that's fine: `I`'s hash ID is unique to *that* commit.

---

#### Rebase

What `git rebase` does, in a nutshell, is to *copy* some commits to new-and-improved versions, and then move a branch name.

Nothing—not you and not Git itself—can *change* any existing commit.  All commits are frozen for all time.  That's what makes the hash IDs work.  But you can take a commit out, and work on it, and make a *new* commit that's just as good as the original in terms of what *changes* it makes, and *better* than the new commit in that it goes in the right place.

That is, suppose you have:

```
          I   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H--J--K   <-- origin/master
```

What if there is an easy way to have Git *copy* existing commit `I` to a new-and-improved commit that comes *after* commit `K`?

There is, and it's `git rebase`.  We run:

```
git rebase origin/master
```

and Git lists out all the commits on our `master` (`I`, `H`, `G`, ... on back) and then strikes out from this list all the commits that are on `origin/master` (`K`, `J`, `H`, `G`, ...).  That leaves commit `I`.  (If we had more commits, such as `I-L`, we'd have that list here, and the next step would copy two commits instead of one.)

Our Git then uses *detached HEAD* mode (which we'll just gloss over) to *copy* each commit, one at a time, to come after commit `K`, the one we named with `origin/master`:

```
          I   <-- master
         /
...--G--H--J--K   <-- origin/master
               \
                I'  <-- HEAD
```

Having copied all the commits, our Git then yanks *our* name `master` over here, to the last-copied commit, and re-attaches `HEAD` to `master`:

```
          I   [abandoned]
         /
...--G--H--J--K   <-- origin/master
               \
                I'  <-- master (HEAD)
```

Since commit `I` does not have a *name*, we won't find it directly, and since `I'` points to `K` which points to `J` which points to `H` which points to `G`, we won't find it that way either.  It will seem as though we somehow altered existing commit `I`.

We didn't—`I'` has a totally different hash ID from `I`—but since we're the only Git that *had* `I`, nobody else needs to know this.  We can now run:

```
git push origin master
```

to send commit `I'` to the other Git, and ask them to set *their* `master` to point to `I'`.  As long as their `master` still points to `K` right now, this will succeed.