# Resolve rebase conflicts easily

Tags: git, git-rebase

When I execute: `git pull --rebase` from my feature branch, I get conflicts in lot of files which I've never edited. To get rid of these conflicts I execute following set of commands for each and every conflicted files.

```
git checkout --ours .

git add .

git rebase --continue
```

The annoying part is I have to execute this for every conflicts. Is there any way to configure git with a custom command so that above all commands will execute at once.

Something like:

```
If(featureBranch_04) {
   foreach(conflicts)
      if(conflictedFile != index.jsp) {
          git checkout --ours .
          git add .
          git rebase --continue
      }
   }
}
```

Can I have a similar function in git config ?

The workflow is: First I merged the master branch into `featureBranch_04`, and then `git pull --rebase` from the `featureBranch_04` branch.

Comment: Why are you doing `git pull --rebase` in the first place? Why not just `git pull` and then rebase your branch afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

You could try a:

```
git fetch
git rebase -s recursive -X theirs origin/featureBranch_04
```

That would [pass the merge strategy '`theirs`'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2945367/6309) to the merge part of a rebase.

Comment: Given that rebase reverses the "ours/theirs" sense, wouldn't "-s theirs" be right?  Or does rebase change user-supplied arguments to match the sense-swap?

Comment: @torek thank you. Fixed. I should have known, I have written extensively about this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3052118/6309