# Can the merge strategy for a Git Interactive Rebase be changed while the rebase is paused?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-interactive-rebase

I am trying to squash all of the commits from my master repo down to one commit within my branch. I am doing this because the master branch is pulled from a remote repo that we don't control whereas the branch in question is pulled/pushed to our own remote git repo (Atlassian Stash). I am doing this because I really don't want or care about all the commit history from the master branch.

I started the whole process using `git rebase --root -i`, within the interactive portion I chose to reword the first commit and fixup the rest (there are about 16000 commits)

Now in the middle of the process the rebase is running into conflicts pretty often and if even half of the commits result in conflicts manually choosing to accept theirs will take a long time.

So when the rebase procedure is stopped because of conflicts is it possible to change the merge strategy to always accept theirs?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4273436/1486275

Comment: Aye that would work great if I had started with it,not sure how I could specify it either on a git rebase -continue   or on its own before calling continue

Comment: OK so I wasn't too far in on the merging I decided to abort and start over specifying the merge strategy. I will however leave the question up because it would be nice to know if this is possible.