# How to rebase detached branch on top of master?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have two branches:
1. master
2. tmp

tmp branch is detached
I need to put tmp branch on top of master with resolving conflicts in priority of tmp ?

Comment: Branches cannot be "detached", only the symbolic reference `HEAD` can be "detached", from a branch.

Answer (score 1):

The term "detached" is generally reserved to "[detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309)", where you have no branch name referencing a commit.

If you have a branch named "`tmp`", it isn't really detached.

The only interpretation I see for this "detached" state would be:

```
x--x--x     (master)
       \
       y--y (b1)
           \
            z--z--z (tmp)
```

(Here, `tmp` could be considered "detached" from `master`, as it doesn't directly stem from master, but from `b1`)

In which case, a rebase would look like

```
git checkout tmp
git rebase --onto master b1 tmp
```

In any case, you can pass a merge strategy to [`git rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) in order to resolve any conflict in favor of tmp content (as I mention in "[Selecting merge strategy options for git rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2945367/6309)"):

```
git rebase -s recursive -X theirs
```