# Git Rebase Strategy Theirs Not Overwriting

Tags: git

I am trying to do a rebase from the develop branch to my feature branch. As noted [in this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945344/how-do-i-select-a-merge-strategy-for-a-git-rebase?answertab=active#tab-top), I want the files with merge conflicts to over write my likewise feature branch files.

However, I am having a difference behavior.

1. Why is `VDPGallery` showing as a file that will be overwritten? It does not show if I do `git merge develop` or `git rebase develop`
2. Why is it telling me  `Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge. Aborting`? This is supposed to overwrite the conflict files automatically. In addition, all my files are pushed and committed before the rebase.

   ```
   $ git rebase -s recursive -X theirs develop
   First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
   error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge
           MarketPlace.Web/Marketplace.WebUI/Scripts/components/VDPGallery
           MarketPlace.Web/Marketplace.WebUI/css/am/site.css
           MarketPlace.Web/Marketplace.WebUI/css/am/site_l.css
           MarketPlace.Web/Marketplace.WebUI/css/am/site_m.css
           MarketPlace.Web/Marketplace.WebUI/css/site.css
           MarketPlace.Web/Marketplace.WebUI/css/site_l.css
           MarketPlace.Web/Marketplace.WebUI/css/site_m.css

   Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.


   Aborting

   Unknown exit code (128) from command: git-merge-recursive 8b499ab98b4f23ad30ab2d5bafd9695f8405f^ -- HEAD 8b499ab98b4f23ad30a3b8b2d5bafd9695f8405f
   ```

Comment: I don't have time to look any closer but this is the sort of error you get when you have *untracked* files in your work-tree, that you'd be rebasing atop *tracked* files that would overwrite your untracked ones.

Comment: What does `git status` say?

Comment: `nothing to commit, working tree clean`. I made sure I had no untracked files.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hint:

`First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it`

It's hard to say without more information, but maybe you've deleted those files locally since the last time you've done rebased, and that change would be overwritten.