# How do I resolve cherry-pick conflicts using their changes?

Tags: git

My `git cherry-pick FOO` produced a conflict.

I could go through the conflicting files and delete the lines between `<<<<<<<` and `=======`, and the conflict markers themselves, but I'm hoping there's an easier way.

I think the `svn` equivalent was choosing `theirs-conflict` to resolve.

How do I do this in `git`?

I don't want `git checkout --theirs <file>` as that seems to produce the same result as `git checkout foo <file>` instead of just getting `git diff FOO~..FOO <file>` applied.

Answer (score 284, accepted):

First you should undo your cherry-pick, try to run this

```
git cherry-pick --abort
```

Second, try to make cherry-pick, but in this time you get their changes not yours, so make this:

```
git cherry-pick --strategy=recursive -X theirs {Imported_Commit}
```

Comment: A bit more information about what those switches are doing is available at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268172/git-merge-recursive-theirs-how-does-it-work

Comment: I tried this exactly: `git cherry-pick --strategy=recursive -X theirs 1b92440` and I'm still prompted for an unresolved conflict: `Unmerged paths: deleted by them: (file path)`. Any idea?

Comment: A more understandable way to reset after a failed cherry-pick/merge is to use `git reset --merge`

Comment: `git cherry-pick --abort` - this is recommended way to undo cherry-pick operation.

Comment: I don't have a `-X` option in `git cherry-pick`. git 1.7.2.3.

Comment: @Frank: this is strange, look at https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html you will see the option -X and its use

Comment: If you still get a conflict, you can resolve the conflicts manually and then run `git cherry-pick --continue`

Comment: didn't work for me, same *umerged paths*, conflict is in deleting files that differ

Comment: AFAICS, `--strategy=recursive` is default unless you configured something else. Leaving it out will shorten the cmd considerably.

Comment: It also was not really working for me. I resolved it by doing `git rm file1 file2 ...`

Comment: Doesn't `-Xtheirs` actually accept "our" changes instead of "their" changes. IOW, doesn't it work like `merge` or `rebase`?